# Room cannot verify the data integrity. How can I fix it without writing migration steps?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have room setup on production app.
I have made many schema related changes to multiple tables in my app.

Before shipping to production build, I have made sure of the following

1. Increase database version
2. have `exportSchema = false` in `@Database` annotation line
3. allowBackup to false in manifest `<application android:allowBackup="false" />`
4. have `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` while creating database
5. have `.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade()` while creating database
6. have `.enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()` while creating database

App crashes with the following stacktrace.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

For development I can clear app cache and data, but how to fix this in production? **I do not wish to write migration steps as there are multiple changes in schema and tables.**

I have read [excellent article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929), but it's not helpful. What are my options?

stacktrace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
   at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run + 92(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1167(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 641(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run + 764(Thread.java:764)
```

/////////////////////////////

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 19 to 20 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.
   at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade + 101(RoomOpenHelper.java:101)
   at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade + 124(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:124)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked + 398(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:398)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase + 298(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
   at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase + 92(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
   at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase + 53(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction + 452(RoomDatabase.java:452)
   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction + 275(RoomDatabase.java:275)
   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query + 304(RoomDatabase.java:304)
   at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query + 54(DBUtil.java:54)
   at com.xxx.data.local.banner.BannerDao_Impl$4.call + 218(BannerDao_Impl.java:218)
   at com.xxx.data.local.banner.BannerDao_Impl$4.call + 215(BannerDao_Impl.java:215)
   at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run + 90(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1167(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 641(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run + 764(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Keep `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` and remove `.fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade()` since the latter overrides the previous setting.

Comment: Tried this but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Room migration issue using the below method.

```
 Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "xxx.db")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationOnDowngrade()
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(16, 17, 18, 19)
        .build()
```

Had to add `fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom()` method which forced dropping tables and recreating tables with new schema.

So varargs of db version eg `16, 17, 18, 19` will recreate db for these version numbers for method `fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom(...)`

Not sure why this method works but`fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` does not work.

Why is this soo weird?

Comment: But does it keep the old data?